# The sum of the multiplied variables

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I need translate to SAS below "filter" from R cran:

```
filter(1:5, f1, method="recursive")
[1]  1  3  6 10 15
```

## equivalent to:

```
x[1]
x[2] + f1*x[1]
x[3] + f1*x[2] + f1^2*x[1]
x[4] + f1*x[3] + f1^2*x[2] + f1^3*x[1]
x[5] + f1*x[4] + f1^2*x[3] + f1^3*x[2] + f1^4*x[1]
```

f1 is integer. I think I should use look. Do you have any idea on solution?

For example:

[image]

My code in the SAS:

```
data have;
  input Variable Value;
datalines;
a 1
a 4
a 5
b 6
b 7
b 10

;
run;


data want;
set have;
by Variable;
%let f1=0.5;
 set have (firstobs=2 keep=Value rename=(Value=LEAD1));
 if last.Variable then LEAD1=.;
  if first.Variable then do;
Out=Value*&f1;
end;
Out=LEAD1*&f1+Value*&f1;
run;
```

This code is working!!!:D

Comment: Please post some clearer sample input and output data, and the SAS code you have tried.

Comment: I added more details:)

Comment: Please could you also show the output you are expecting for each row of input?

Comment: I added output in the above table

Comment: Sorry, that image is blocked in my location. Please post your output as text as part of the question.

Comment: Also, please describe in detail how you are trying to generate the output from the input. What's the algorithm?

Comment: Guys my code is working :D I found solution, thank you:)